# Advertising info link points to the current url

Tags: bug, status-completed

Not that I regard it as a particularly major bug ...

Comment: can you elaborate? what do you mean?

Comment: Right down at the bottom of the page ... no, a bit further ... up a bit ... yup, just there ... there's a line of links starting "about | faq | blog | ...".  The one labelled "advertising info" points to the url of whatever page it is you're on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed, feel free to contact us for advertising rates at *fantastic* discounts now! :)

Comment: Great!  That's taken a load of my mind.  Incidentally, is there some badge for asking a question that you've answered?  I feel that it should be worthy of some note!